# Why Magenta is preprocessing less outputs than inputs?

Tags: tensorflow, pipeline, recurrent-neural-network, midi, magenta

I am using Magenta's [Polyphony RNN](https://github.com/magenta/magenta/tree/master/magenta/models/polyphony_rnn) to generate MIDI music. I have the dataset, but when it comes to Magenta's preprocessing, it produces fewer outputs than I expected to produce (it should be the same as inputs). I can observe that there are some metrics to get rid of the inputs, but I don't really understand which or why are they being used.

I don't really understand either how can I get the exact amount of inputs I don't get as outputs (some pipelines generate multiple variations).

Attached to this post, I'll leave one screenshot of how is the log of the pipeline once it has processed everything:

Polyphony RNN pipeline log:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Processed 3902 inputs total. Produced 819 outputs.
I0426 09:22:31.260396 140551050180416 pipeline.py:388] Processed 3902 inputs total. Produced 819 outputs.
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_eval_polyphonic_track_lengths_in_bars:
  [1,10): 9
  [10,20): 45
I0426 09:22:31.260454 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_eval_polyphonic_track_lengths_in_bars:
  [1,10): 9
  [10,20): 45
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_eval_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_more_than_1_program: 13317
I0426 09:22:31.260496 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_eval_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_more_than_1_program: 13317
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_eval_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_too_long: 81
I0426 09:22:31.260534 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_eval_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_too_long: 81
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_eval_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_too_short: 9135
I0426 09:22:31.260581 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_eval_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_too_short: 9135
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_training_polyphonic_track_lengths_in_bars:
  [1,10): 369
  [10,20): 234
  [20,30): 162
I0426 09:22:31.260628 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_training_polyphonic_track_lengths_in_bars:
  [1,10): 369
  [10,20): 234
  [20,30): 162
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_training_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_more_than_1_program: 119675
I0426 09:22:31.260667 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_training_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_more_than_1_program: 119675
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_training_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_too_long: 711
I0426 09:22:31.260702 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_training_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_too_long: 711
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_training_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_too_short: 133902
I0426 09:22:31.260736 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_training_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_too_short: 133902
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_RandomPartition_eval_poly_tracks_count: 388
I0426 09:22:31.260771 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_RandomPartition_eval_poly_tracks_count: 388
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_RandomPartition_training_poly_tracks_count: 3514
I0426 09:22:31.260805 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_RandomPartition_training_poly_tracks_count: 3514
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_TranspositionPipeline_eval_skipped_due_to_range_exceeded: 30
I0426 09:22:31.260839 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_TranspositionPipeline_eval_skipped_due_to_range_exceeded: 30
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_TranspositionPipeline_eval_transpositions_generated: 22587
I0426 09:22:31.260874 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_TranspositionPipeline_eval_transpositions_generated: 22587
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_TranspositionPipeline_training_skipped_due_to_range_exceeded: 187
I0426 09:22:31.260908 140551050180416 statistics.py:137] DAGPipeline_TranspositionPipeline_training_skipped_due_to_range_exceeded: 187
INFO:tensorflow:DAGPipeline_TranspositionPipeline_training_transpositions_generated: 255053
```

**The relevant snippet of code in which these songs are filtered, is found with the metric executed between lines [447 - 453](https://github.com/magenta/magenta/blob/102cbdedb1002c8ca21f4d546a854819fd72ca70/magenta/models/polyphony_rnn/polyphony_lib.py#L412), which is called *DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_training_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_more_than_1_program***

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, would you add the relevant code that is leading to this situation?

Comment: @WurmD Actually, currently my problem is in the "DAGPipeline_PolyExtractor_training_polyphonic_tracks_discarded_more_than_1_program" metric, as half of the MIDI tracks in the dataset I use contain more than one instrument.

My questions are:

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?
Is this a normal thing, or is someone working on it so that it is somehow done automatically?

Anyway, the relevant snippet of code is between lines 447 - 453 ([Code](https://github.com/magenta/magenta/blob/102cbdedb1002c8ca21f4d546a854819fd72ca70/magenta/models/polyphony_rnn/polyphony_lib.py#L412))